# How to make two Elastic Beanstalk environments share one database instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a rails elastic beanstalk application with two environments, staging and production. When creating the application and staging environment with `eb init` i created a database instance. I used the eb console to create the production environment and created a new database instance which i perceive is obviously a wrong move.

How do i make my two environments share the same database instance? If that happens, how about when i update the database migrations in my app and deploy to the staging; it means my users would see it because the same database is used by staging environment.

How to i handle this issue?

I also noticed `git aws.push` doesn't overwrite my database but it doesn't remove rolled back migrations. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend to you following option: Create rds instance outside of the elastic beanstalk environment. Create separate schemas for production and staging. Pass connections strings to your EBS application. Shared rds instance between EBS environments will help to you:

1. Decrease cost of your environment, because to have several rds instances running is expensive.
2. Help to you isolate production and staging environments.

Comment: If i want to agree with you, how do i push my database from localhost independently to the new RDS instance? Remember its rails and a <code>git aws.push</code> does the deployment but with your solution not anymore. So how?

Comment: You can add to your application folder .ebextentions with config files which will contain configuration settings like connection string to db and scripts to run migrations. I would suggest to read article: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_custom_container.html

Comment: I will try to explain my idea one more time be steps: 1. You can manually create rds instance and schemas for production and staging. 2. You can add to your application elastic beanstalk configuration files, where you can define connection string for current database related with staging or production, also you can define here commands for running migrations. 3. To do git aws.push :)